# What does it mean to "look it"?

Tags: phrases, sense-verbs

What does the emphasized part of the following excerpt mean? It's from an edition of *2001: A Space Odyssey*.

> She had been assembled in orbit around the Earth, tested on a translunar maiden flight, and finally checked out in orbit above the Moon. She was a creature of pure space -- and **she looked it**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is qualifying the preceding statement. It is saying that the ship is not only a "creature of pure space", but that it *looks* as though it is a creature of pure space.

This phrase is quite common (emphasis is mine):

> He was most fifty, and **he looked it**. His hair was long and tangled and greasy, and hung down, and you could see his eyes shining through like he was behind vines. It was all black, no gray; so was his long, mixed-up whiskers.
>
> (From *The Adventures of Huckleberry Finn* by Mark Twain)

> He was sick, he said, and **he looked it**.
>
> (From *Tom Sawyer* by Mark Twain)

> At this point, the door opened, and Mr. Bucket walked into the room. He was cold and tired, and **he looked it**. All day long, he had been working in the streets.
>
> (From *Charlie and The Chocolate Factory* by Roald Dahl)

> He was a pedant, to the most extreme point, the greatest pedant I had met on earth, and with that had a vanity only befitting Alexander of Macedon. He was in love with every button on his coat, every nail on his fingers--absolutely in love with them, and **he looked it!**
>
> (From *Notes From the Underground* by Fyodor Dostoevsky)

I love this one. The sentence invokes an image of the man being so overly proud of appearance!

Comment: Thanks, I had only heard it as _he looked **like** it_. Is this construct actually used in modern speech as well?

Comment: Absolutely. It's just that searching on the internet tends to bring up older texts, since they're more freely available.

Comment: @Tim: It may help you to understand how this works if you think of this usage as being like *He looked tired*: we could say *He was tired, and he looked tired*, but that's repetitive, so the second *tired* is replaced by a pronoun: *He was tired, and he looked it*.

Comment: @psmears: I hadn't thought of it like that. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The *it*, in your example, refers to the state of being a creature of pure space.

*looked it*, in this instance, is used to give emphasis to the the previous observation.

> He was completely exhausted from traveling across the desert for eight days, and he looked it.

The emphasis relies on the idea that looks can be deceiving. So someone could be a *creature of pure space* and yet not look it.

For example, the Emperor of Japan in the mid to late 19th century lived in a great palace and was dressed in the finest silks, waited on hand a foot, etc. He looked like a descendant of the Sun Goddess.

Saigo Takamori, on the other hand, was a politician and military officer of some renown and high standing, but he did not look it. In fact it has been reported on one occasion that when he left the Emperor's palace that he was arrested because he looked of such lowly standing the guard did not believe he could have any business being in the palace.

Answer (score 0):

“Acknowledge what I’m showing you”. Is how I use it...must have learned it as a child, because I use it all the time...so do my kids and now my grandkids.  I didn’t even know I used it...something that must have just stuck with me from my youth.  Urban gives this definition :

Lookit
Abbreviation of "look at that" or "look at this," typically uttered shrilly in public places by small children seeking to draw attention to mundane objects that they, for some reason, consider fascinating.
Lookit! A kitty cat! Lookit, mommy! Lookit!

Comment: That's what the title sounds like, but if you read the contents of this question, t's not asking about 'lookit' by itself. It's about the pattern '[noun] looked [predicate]' meaning the noun had the appearance of being [predicate], and then the predicate replaced by a the pronoun 'it'.